# Will connecting an Exchange account to my Mac enable remote wipe?

Tags: security, remote-control, exchange

I know that connecting an Exchange account to an iPhone can give the Exchange administrators the ability to force a Passcode change or remotely wipe the device, but is this possible on a Macbook/OS X/macOS client?

Answer (score 3):

The only supported devices for remote wipe are: Android, iOS, Windows. macOS is not supported.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/intune-classic/deploy-use/use-remote-wipe-to-help-protect-data-using-microsoft-intune

inTune features for macOS are listed here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/intune-user-help/using-your-ios-or-macos-device-with-intune

Comment: Is OS X and macOS interchangeable? ie, do they have the same version continuum?

Comment: I believe Apple retroactively renamed Mac OS X and OS X to macOS.

Comment: Usually. Apple did a brand name change for Sierra 10.12 to macOS (effectively rewinding the o.s. marketing back to 1997!), previous versions ≤10.11 were Mac OS X or OS X. MS InTune supports 10.9+

Comment: @sansSpoon These links are not very conclusive to me. How do I know my company uses Intune/MDM and how can I be certain that simply connecting a calendar on my Mac will give the Exchange tools the ability to remote wipe (or not)?

Comment: It will all depend on what parts of Exchange and InTune your I.T. department are running and if they are using profiles. As far as I know there is no way to tell what profiles are in use until you join the domain.

Comment: @sansSpoon ok so my Mac is *not* on the domain. I simply have added my work Exchange account to my Calendar app in OS X. Is it safe to assume the remote wipe can't be performed under this arrangement?